# How to apply the click function to alert controller and change the language in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I am working on multilingual app in Ionic 4 and I have used the alert controller for showing the languages but the problem is that how to change the language when the user selects the particular language.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
language: any = 'en';
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.initializeApp();
}

initializeApp() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    const browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
    this.translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
   });
}

 async changeLanguage() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Language',
      inputs: [{
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'English',
        value: 'en',
        checked: this.language === 'en'
      }, {
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'French',
        value: 'fr',
        checked: this.language === 'fr'
      }],
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel'
      }, {
        text: 'OK',
        handler: selectedLanguage => {
          this.language = selectedLanguage;
        }
      }]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

This is my **app.component.html**:

```
<button ion-button icon-end (click)="changeLanguage()">
    <span>{{language | uppercase }}</span>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

When I open the App, the default language selected is English and I want to change the language according to the user select the language from the alert box.

I have added the `ngx-translate` plugin.

This is my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
      }
  }) ],
})
```

The default selected language is English.

Using the {`{ 'ACCOUNT_TAB_LAB' | translate }}` translate pipe in very html, I have to import the `import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';` in each sub modules but I think this is not good.

Do, I have to create a service for this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can get the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000630/the-pipe-translate-could-not-be-found-error-is-showing-in-ionic-4/ It will solve your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can solve this problem like this also.**

[The pipe 'translate' could not be found error is showing In Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000630/the-pipe-translate-could-not-be-found-error-is-showing-in-ionic-4/)

This is the best way to apply click function and use the translator.

It will solve your query.